# Jenkins freestyle build run with allure report

Tags: python, jenkins, pytest

I'm running a jenkins freestyle build for all tests that contain pytest marker "jenkins_run" and after build run, i want allure report for my tests.
what i tried is:

```
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Perforce\depot2\Cloud\TestAutomation\framework

python -m pytest --alluredir="reportpath" -rf -m jenkins_run
```

What's happening is that tests are running fine but allure is not able to pick test result from the specified path
(attaching screenshot for reference).

Build command:

[image]

Post build actions for allure

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've struggled with this as well. for me, the issue was that the path in "--alluredir" parameter didn't match one of the allure plugin.

make sure the path of --alluredir is:

1. must be folder called exactly 'allure-result' (at least for my version the configuration of the allure jenkins plugin is a lie)
2. relative to jenkins workspace and **to your specific build folder** inside the 
   workspace

so, it should look something like:

```
--alluredir "path/of/jenkins/workspace/build_name/target/allure-result"
```